# CSS hyperlink code is not working

Tags: html, css

I have a corner link that will not conform to my css code: 
The code editor here did not transform it to the corner like JSFiddle does.
[My JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/jayt_rle/7vj4379z/14/)
I do not want to see the hyperlink underlines or the browser default hyperlink colors. If I remove the z-index, it removes the text as well. I will put this code on a website when I get it working so it needs to stay on top of everything. What am I doing wrong here?

```css
<style type="text/css">
.element{  
 height: 35px;
    width: 140px;
    background-color: #fffea1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 15px;
    right: -30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #830303;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 24px;
    white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(35deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(35deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(35deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(35deg);
    transform: rotate(35deg);
}
.element:before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 37px;
    border-left-width: 53px;
    border-right-width: 26px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    left: -49px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 141%;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-color: #fffea1;
    top: -2px;
    z-index: -1;
}
a.element:link
{
   color: #830303;
   text-decoration: none;
}
a.element:visited
{
   color: #830303;
   text-decoration: none;
}
a.element:hover
{
   color: #830303;
   text-decoration: none;
}
a.element:active
{
   color: #830303;
   text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="element"><a href="know.html" target="_blank">KNOW</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the default `a` styling with `color` and `text-decoration`:

```
.element a {
    color: #ff0000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

---

Make sure to include `a {` at the end of your CSS rule, to override any default styling. Just targeting `.element {` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to add this code to your CSS to change color of link and remove underline:

```
a{
  color:black;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
.element{  
 height: 35px;
    width: 140px;
    background-color: #fffea1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 15px;
    right: -30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #830303;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 24px;
    white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(35deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(35deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(35deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(35deg);
    transform: rotate(35deg);
}
.element:before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 37px;
    border-left-width: 53px;
    border-right-width: 26px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    left: -49px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 141%;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-color: #fffea1;
    top: -2px;
    z-index: -1;
}
a{
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
}
a.element:link
{
   color: #830303;
   text-decoration: none;
}
a.element:visited
{
   color: #830303;
   text-decoration: none;
}
a.element:hover
{
   color: #830303;
   text-decoration: none;
}
a.element:active
{
   color: #830303;
   text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="element"><a href="know.html" target="_blank">KNOW</a></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your support. the code is working perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Your current CSS for the hyperlinks is targeting `a.element` which is not the correct selector. That is looking for a tag `<a>` that itself has a class name `element` ...

Your actual HTML is: a `div` with `class="element"` that *contains a child tag* `a` ...

See [this CSS Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/whats-the-difference/) for the difference between `el.className` vs `.className childElements`

One solution is to change your CSS to target that pattern instead: 
`.element a` which targets all descendant `a` tags within `<someTag>` that has class `element`

Also, "element" is not a great choice for a class name, as pretty much everything on the page is an HTML "element." Choose something more descriptive.

Also also, since you're not changing the text color (why not?) don't repeat the CSS rules for each psuedo-element. Just put them on `.element a` or `a` directly to set a default text color & remove text-decoration from *every* link on the page. Then change only colors or font size etc when a link is in a different state.

As for `z-index` ... Don't bother, and get a newer HTML/CSS book or tutorial. 
Look into the "box model" and how `position: fixed` works vs. alternatives. You shouldn't need to use hard-coded pixel values & positioning for everything.

```css
<style type="text/css">
.element{  
 height: 35px;
    width: 140px;
    background-color: #fffea1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 15px;
    right: -30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #830303;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 24px;
    white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(35deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(35deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(35deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(35deg);
    transform: rotate(35deg);
}
.element:before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 37px;
    border-left-width: 53px;
    border-right-width: 26px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    left: -49px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 141%;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-color: #fffea1;
    top: -2px;
    z-index: -1;
}
.element a
{
   color: #830303;
   text-decoration: none;
}
.element a:visited
{
   color: #830303;
}
.element a:hover
{
   color: #830303;
}
.element a:active
{
   color: #830303;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="element"><a href="know.html" target="_blank">KNOW</a></div>
```

Comment: I appreciate the explanation and the CSS Tricks article. It has been ten plus years since I have played with web design.